# Change "Next"/"Previous" link titles in fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I am trying (with fancybox 2.0.6) to change link titles ('Next', 'Previous') to something different:

```
beforeLoad: function() {
      jQuery('.fancybox-next').each(function() {
        var $this = jQuery(this);
        $this.attr('title', 'Далі');
      });
    }
```

Please, what is wrong? Am I trying to use right callback? Something else?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change the `title` attribute of `next` and `prev` links using the `tpl` option this way

```
$("a.fancybox").fancybox({
 tpl: {
  next: '<a title="Siguiente" class="fancybox-nav fancybox-next"><span></span></a>',
  prev: '<a title="Anterior" class="fancybox-nav fancybox-prev"><span></span></a>'
 }
}); // fancybox
```

Comment: Great!! Who could imagine ,) "tpl: Object containing various templates". THANK YOU! Where can I read more about "variuos templates"?

Answer (score 2):

They have a better documentation now at their new website: 
http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs

Possible TPLs:

```
{
    wrap     : '<div class="fancybox-wrap" tabIndex="-1"><div class="fancybox-skin"><div class="fancybox-outer"><div class="fancybox-inner"></div></div></div></div>',
    image    : '<img class="fancybox-image" src="{href}" alt="" />',
    iframe   : '<iframe id="fancybox-frame{rnd}" name="fancybox-frame{rnd}" class="fancybox-iframe" frameborder="0" vspace="0" hspace="0"' + ($.browser.msie ? ' allowtransparency="true"' : '') + '></iframe>',
    error    : '<p class="fancybox-error">The requested content cannot be loaded.<br/>Please try again later.</p>',
    closeBtn : '<a title="Close" class="fancybox-item fancybox-close" href="javascript:;"></a>',
    next     : '<a title="Next" class="fancybox-nav fancybox-next" href="javascript:;"><span></span></a>',
    prev     : '<a title="Previous" class="fancybox-nav fancybox-prev" href="javascript:;"><span></span></a>'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a common problem when using jquery plugins.
the general solution is replace plugin's default options with custom options.
for fancybox, the default options that related to "next" and "prev"  are as follow:

```
  tpl: {
    next     : '<a title="Next" class="fancybox-nav fancybox-next" href="javascript:;"><span></span></a>',
    prev     : '<a title="Previous" class="fancybox-nav fancybox-prev" href="javascript:;"><span></span></a>'
    },
```

just replace it with your custom when using fancybox.

Answer (score 0):

This is now done in the jquery.fancybox.js file ... just scroll down to where it says Localization and change the words next and previous to whatever you want.